# How to check debuggable or debug build type in android library?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-buildconfig

I have an Android AAR library. One security policy I want to impose on the consumer application of my library, is that it must not be able to use my library when `debuggable` is true or the apk is created using the `debug buildType.`

How can I check this programmatically in android ?

Comment: you can check your library's `build.gradle` to detect if its debug or not but how are you going to check the consumer's `build.gradle`?

Comment: @KostasDrakonakis that's exactly the problem :)

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi but what is the reason? The important point is that your library is not in debug. Everyone develop the app in debug mode.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti this is a security check for the release of the consumer application, which is going to be distributed to end users.

Comment: You can get the value in buildconfig like this `getApplicationContext().getResources().getString("BuildConfig Res Value")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a workaround with reflection in order to get the project's(not library's) BuildConfig value like this:

```
/**
 * Gets a field from the project's BuildConfig. This is useful when, for example, flavors
 * are used at the project level to set custom fields.
 * @param context       Used to find the correct file
 * @param fieldName     The name of the field-to-access
 * @return              The value of the field, or {@code null} if the field is not found.
 */
public static Object getBuildConfigValue(Context context, String fieldName) {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(context.getPackageName() + ".BuildConfig");
        Field field = clazz.getField(fieldName);
        return field.get(null);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

To get the `DEBUG` field, for example, just call this from library `Activity`:

```
boolean debug = (Boolean) getBuildConfigValue(this, "DEBUG");
```

I have not tried this yet and cannot guarantee it will work all the time but you can go ahead!!!

Comment: seems legit. I'll try and let you know of the result.

Comment: This will not work and return null if minifyEnabled is set to true in app's build.gradle. This is not a recommended method to use in a library.

Answer (score 11):

Check `debuggable` tag on AndroidManifest file is the better way:

```
public static boolean isDebuggable(Context context) {
    return ((context.getApplicationInfo().flags 
            & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0);
}
```